# How do I enable Vim bindings in GNOME Text Editor?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-text-editor

In the [Gitlab page for GNOME Text Editor](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-text-editor), it mentions that this app has this feature:

- Integrated support for Vim keybindings

How do I enable Vim key bindings for GNOME Text Editor? (Note that I'm talking about GNOME Text Editor, not gedit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how. Open the command-line, and run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.TextEditor keybindings vim
```

This is assuming that you are using GNOME Text Editor installed from APT, and not Flatpak or another installation method.

```
sudo apt install gnome-text-editor
```

That's it! Now you have enabled Vim key bindings in GNOME Text Editor.

---

To reset the key bindings back the default setting, run:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.TextEditor keybindings
```

Comment: On ubuntu 22.04.01 I get `No such schema “org.gnome.TextEditor”`

Comment: @MDeBusk Do you have the APT package installed? `sudo apt install gnome-text-editor`

Comment: That's surprising. No, I didn't. I thought I had, but it appears that Ubuntu comes installed with a symbolic link between `gedit` and `gnome-text-editor`. I installed the apt package and was able to set the vim keybindings as instructed. But I quickly removed it because it seems painfully slow and buggy.